# Navicat backup restoring - [Err] Failed to create View

Tags: mysql, view, database-backups, navicat, mysql-backup

I was testing the restoring of my database backup
and when it comes to the **views**, most of them are restored but for some views it gives me an **Error**

I went to check the view, the view has a select statement that selects from another view.

My question is, is there a way to force it to restore the view even though it has an error?

I solved it by copying the select query of the view, and creating a new view with the same name.. it works perfectly but what if I completely lost the **schema / server **and all i have is the backup file
[Navicat view restore ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7QS0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem was in the functions, the views were using functions that hasn't been restored yet in the schema.

To be more clear, The restore goes "Tables > Views > Functions > Events"
So i had to restore first "Tables > Functions > Events" Then i would restore the views, it worked perfectly fine.